# How to debug postgres when there are no users?

Tags: postgresql

What to do if there appear to be no users on the server: any attempt to connect to the server gives `FATAL:  role ".." does not exist`, including the role "postgres". It's only possible to connect in single user mode and the pg_user table (view?) appears to be empty (`select count(*) from pg_user;` is null).

Below I assumed the database process doesn't start -- it does. It's just that the `systemctl start postgresql` command hangs because after starting the postgres server it then runs a shell script which loops `psql` to connect to the server, and this never returns as there is no postgres role..

---

### Original question

I've somehow managed to create a situation where there are no users, not even the superuser `postgres`. I can get into single user mode with `postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/data` but nothing else works, and the systemd service loops on the error `FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`.

Whit might have created this and how to fix it?

- OS: NixOS, `23.05.4603.3e10c80821de (Stoat)`
- Postgres version: `postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.9`, installed via the nixos module

Tried thus far

- `postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data` does start the server, but there is no way to get in, user `postgres` does not help, `sudo` neither
- `postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/mnt_14` gets me into the single user mode (this is totally new to me). In there running `select count(*) from pg_user;` gives "0" as the result, inserting into that table doesn't work.
- in single user mode none of the backslash commands work, difficult to explore the situation

Comment: Can you give [createuser](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html) a try? Most likely it will fail, but the error output could provide insight.

Comment: Not easy to do that: `# DROP USER postgres;
ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped`

Comment: @Travis `createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist` -- i.e, it needs some user to run the action

Comment: Wonder if initiating a fresh database and then rsyncing the existing tables in, would work?

Comment: More information needed: 1) OS and version. 2) Postgres version.  3) How was Postgres installed? 4) Have there been any system or database crashes recently? 5) Is the database open to remote access? 6) Do you have recent backup?

Comment: I would say doing an rsync is not going to work, not least of all  you will be bringing over corrupted tables. There are also all the other files that are specific to the state of the  database cluster and they won't match.

Comment: Can you run [CREATE USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) from inside single user mode?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've added some version info. Recently I restored a large .sql file and it did did work after that. It has also worked before quite reliably for a long time.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that *...it did did work...* should be *...it did not work...*?  If so: 1) Where did the file come from? 2) Have you looked in the file for `CREATE/DROP ROLE` commands? 3) What user/role did you use to run the restore?

Comment: FYI, per suggestion from @Travis I confirmed you can use `CREATE USER` in single user mode. **WARNING**, before doing that and assuming the SQL script was your problem I would thoroughly check what that script did before opening the database cluster up to use.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried to `CREATE USER postgres`, this results in `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_authid_rolname_index". DETAIL:  Key (rolname)=(postgres) already exists.`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the suggestion to at the `create/drop role` statements of the import, am looking into it! Regarding the did/didn't it work: it *did* work.

Comment: Hmm. 1) Next time you go into single user mode do `select count(*) from pg_authid;` 2) When did connection to the database cluster stop working?

Comment: There are 11 rows in pg_authid. There doesn't seem to be anything confidential in there, so pasted the result here as well https://pastebin.com/3LfMy8bL

Comment: When you start the server with `postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data` and then do `psql -d postgres -U postgres` what happens?

Comment: When you're in single mode and start psql, what does the query `SELECT current_user;` return?

Comment: `sudo -u postgres postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data` starts the server, but any attempt to connect to it results in `FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist` in postgres logs

Comment: Why do you have `postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/mnt_14` and `postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/data`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've just tried to use the `data` suffix everywhere -- it actually is `mnt_14`, simply tried to rip out anything that is specific to my install :)

Comment: Don't do that, editorializing while troubleshooting just drives you further into the wreck. So per @FrankHeikens, what does `SELECT current_user;` return in single user mode?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I get `ERROR:  invalid role OID: 10`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to drop all users is a direct `DELETE` to `pg_authid`.  Whoever does that deserves to suffer.  Still, here is how to create the role `postgres` again:

- start the server in single-user mode
- run this statement:

  ```
  CREATE ROLE postgres SUPERUSER LOGIN SYSID 10
  ```
- exit the session (which stops the server)

The trick here is that the bootstrap superuser (usually `postgres` always has object ID 10, so creating a superuser with that object ID is the right thing.

Since a lot of things could be broken in that database if you deleted other rows from `pg_authid`, you should try and get the server into a condition where you can `pg_dump` the data, then restore them to a healthy cluster.

Comment: Recent comment from OP seems to indicate `pg_authid` has at least `postgres` entry.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thrue. But then the question is bogus, since a connection attempt would not give you that error message.

Comment: The result from `CREATE ROLE ..` is the same with `CREATE USER ..` from a comment above: `[29740] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_authid_rolname_index"
[29740] DETAIL:  Key (rolname)=(postgres) already exists.
[29740] STATEMENT:  CREATE ROLE postgres SUPERUSER LOGIN SYSID 10;`

Comment: For info, I've also rebooted without any improvement..

Comment: Then you must have told us something wrong in your question. First, systemd should be able to start the service if you can start the server manually (check the service file to see what it actually does). Second, you wouldn't get that error message if the user existed. We would need much more detail to understand what is going on. Remember how exactly you got into this mess. Hire an expert who can debug this if the data are valuable.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Following your advice I now went and looked at the systemd service file and you were correct in that the service actually does start! But as the `systemctl start` also tries to connect to the server with `psql` then the command never returns. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-23.05/nixos/modules/services/databases/postgresql.nix#L525-L568

Comment: That looks like the package install script. Are you changing Postgres versions?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No, it has been on (major) version 14 all the time (there might have been minor version upgrades, though I think those shouldn't cause this).

Comment: Great, we are getting closer. Please start in single-user mode and run `SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolcanlogin FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'`. Add the output to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I get an empty result. Hmm, the entire issue seems to be that there are no users and I can't add them normally as I can't connect with psql.

Comment: This is very bad and looks like your cluster is toast. The last hope is that there is some kind of index corruption. In single-user mode, try `VACUUM (FULL) pg_authid`. Perhaps that either makes user `postgres` visible or removes all its traces, so that you can add it again. If that does not work either, switch to desperation mode and `TRUNCATE pg_authid`, followed by the `CREATE ROLE` statement. Before you do any of this, save all the cluster's files while the cluster is shut down, since these activities can destroy something valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new cluster and then a database. Since you had tried to run server from absolute path, try creating the cluster from an absolute path. If you are on bin directory in the terminal run `initdb` command in your bin directory to create a cluster and then `createdb` to create a database.